# Windows location settings detecting location with VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, geolocation

I was just curious as to how windows 10 location services (the built into the operating system location tracking) knows your city even if you are using a VPN how would it know? I know I can turn this feature off but the very nature that it knows through my VPN is concerning and I can not figure out how?

I am using open VPN on my router so all traffic goes through my VPN.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways Windows can detect your physical location.  If your public IP was ever exposed to Windows, it can detect your location based on that.  Another method is your wireless card.  There are many companies that have huge databases of WiFi networks with their positions that are used by Microsoft to pin down locations.  Connecting a smartphone to your computer can allow it access to to the GPS location.  Even your timezone and data you enter into web forms can point to your location.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a "travel router" along with a LAN cable and wifi set to off.
Specifically in cases like me where administrator has "force enabled" location services. Obviously, not all "Technical" people will understand this.

Hey I am in the same predicament and a simple experiment helped me understand a lot. Per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-location-service-and-privacy-3a8eee0a-5b0b-dc07-eede-2a5ca1c49088#WindowsVersion=Windows_11

Windows uses nearby access points to determine location. The experiment is to not connect any wifi and just switch on the wifi.
On the "maps" app, it instantly displays the location as soon as you just switch on the wifi, and the location disappears when we switch of the wifi.